# In the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, what makes a superposition of states split in two separate ones?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I was wondering, what agent makes a superposition of, let´s say, the two spins of an electron, máke them split into two separate ones (up and down). And is this not in contradiction to the law of conservation of energy? Or are all the states already there? But if all the states are already there, why should superpositions exist?

And íf all the outcomes of the reduction of superpositions already exist, where do they exist?

I can´t help thinking of block time when I think about this interpretation (with wich I don´t agree).

Comment: There is no well-defined theory that answers these questions and the founders of the "many worlds" philosophy - in particular, Everett and DeWitt, a key early champion - disagreed about all the details that could be a part of the answer, just like most of the current "many worlds" partisans disagree. Don't expect any sensible answer to any of these questions, the theory just doesn't make sense to the extent that it could be quantatively discussed by actual physicists.

Comment: @LubošMotl It's not a theory, it's an interpretation

Comment: MWI "explains" the collapse of the wave function by eliminating it.  Instead, the same mystery which causes wave function collapse in the Copenhagen interpretation here cause the splitting of the universe.  From a small mystery MWI begets a great mystery!

Comment: Can´t it be a deterministic agent that causes the superposition to split into two separate ones, in wich case q.m. is deterministic? I can´t imagine that pure probability is an agent. In my view, there has to be some kind of determination around. In other words, the probability is an illusion, as it was in the case of the movement of the Brown-particle. And what about energy? Does the energy of the Universe doubles with every splitting of a superposition into two separate ones?

Comment: @Dirk, what you wrote is a deep misunderstanding. One can't take quantum mechanics and change its "interpretation". Instead, quantum mechanics *is* the interpretation. Quantum mechanical theories share some basic rules, the so-called universal postulates of quantum mechanics. They were defined by Heisenberg, Born, Jordan, Bohr, Dirac, and others, and deniers of quantum mechanics like to dismiss them as "just an interpretation". But these postulates aren't "just an interpretation". They're the very heart of the theory and it cannot be changed.

Comment: To modify any statement about the probabilistic character of the predictions, the formulae for them, the dependence of the predictions on the observers or observations, the change of the state induced by an observation, or any of these things is proposing a different *theory*, and no theory different from the actual correct quantum mechanical theory is compatible with the body of empirical evidence that are relevant for these questions.

Comment: @LubošMotl An "Interpretation" is the bolt-on explanation people try to give which is "What Really Happens". Only if it provides testable predictions that differ from "conventional" QM is it a new theory.

Comment: @DirkBruere - again, quantum mechanics does clearly say what "really" happens. It says that nothing "really happens" before the experiment and only probabilities of outcomes may be predicted by physical theories. To contradict these basic claims means to deny quantum mechanics. The word "Copenhagen interpretation" was introduced by Heisenberg in the 1950s  (original "Copenhagen spirit" around 1930) and he was sorry about the choice of words already before the book with this phrase came out exactly because he would know it would be abused by deniers of quantum mechanics to claim they can choose

Comment: @LubošMotl QM does not say anything beyond the mathematics. Perhaps you would care to comment on the Born Rule in this context

Comment: No, quantum mechanics is a physical theory, not (just) a mathematical one. It is *primarily* the set of rules connecting the mathematical objects to the physical concepts (from the experiments). In particular, the Born rule is an inseparable part of quantum mechanics. It says that probabilities of observations may be predicted and computed as $|c_i|^2$ from amplitudes. No physical theory would exist and no application of the mathematics of QM would be possible without this rule, Born got a Nobel, it is absolutely fundamental and the talk that it may be reintepreted or interpreted away is silly

Comment: There exists and there can exist no derivation of the Born rule from something that is fundamentally inequivalent to the Born rule. In particular, all papers talking about many worlds and claiming to have "derived the Born rule" are either demonstrably wrong or demonstrably circular. Observations have to be connected to the maths in some way for a physical theory to exist and the connection saying that (only) probabilities are calculable and how is clearly the most direct, irreducible way how to connect the mathematics with the natural science and it's the way labeled as correct by QM (theory)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to your question is that nobody knows.

Quantum mechanics makes a wide range of predictions in extremely close accordance with the results of experiment, so it has an exceptional degree of validity as a mathematical model. However, many people are unsatisfied with it conceptually, and have put forward various suggestions (known as 'interpretations') about what 'really' happens (which, incidentally, implicitly assumes there is a further level of reality- a contestable issue in itself).

The point to bear in mind about the possible interpretations is that we are unable, as yet, to prove or disprove them- they are speculation open to all sorts of conjecture and reinterpretation. The media are fond of extrapolating the more outlandish reinterpretations to produce sensationalist articles, which simply generates further debate and reinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

“And is this not in contradiction to the law of conservation of energy?”

Matter and energy are conserved.

“ And íf all the outcomes of the reduction of superpositions already exist, where do they exist?”

Everything exists in some vector of Hilbert Space.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between the various models suggesting multiple universes and one needs to be careful which of these models they are actually referring to.  For example, parallel universes were suggested with the idea that any thing that might happen will happen and all of these possibilities manifest themselves in different universes.  This is similar to the idea of the many worlds model.

The multiverse concept is actually quite different.  In the multiverse model, the quantum effects that were at play in establishing our universe continue, because of the very nature that they are quantized, and new worlds (universes), with very different physical properties continue, and will continue, to form.

Answer (score -1):

In multiverse there is a multiversal scientist that interacts with an electron that is in two states: up and down. The interaction causes the multiversal scientist to start to evolve to all kinds of directions in Hilbert-space. After a while two distinct blobs in Hilbert-space have been formed: Blob 1 consists of scientists that say: "I interacted with an up-electron". Blob 2 consists of scientists that say: "I interacted with a down-electron".

Those two are the main two types of scientists that result from the interaction with the electron. More odd results also exist, for example the scientists that went to the state of being dead as a result of the interaction.

Well actually the dead scientists can still be divided in two groups: Killed by an up-electron, and killed by a down-electron.

Comment: It is easy to see that there can't be any universal well-defined yet experimentally viable rule for your vague words such as "blobs" and "splitting the blobs". Quantum mechanics is important *especially* in the situations in which the wave function isn't separated to blobs. For example, a brain is a bound state of many nuclei and electrons and its phase space is totally contiguous - there's no "spare room" and there are no blobs in it. But quantum mechanics has to describe what's observed by neurons etc.

Comment: Can I have an upvote then, for illuminating the vagueness of MWI  :)  Why does the alive Schrodingen's cat not see a photon emitted by the dead cat? The photon's phase space is totally contiguous, so total effect of photon is zero, so dead and alive cat can't become entangled, so they kind of like exist in two different universes. Why was the phase phase of the photon contiguous? There was a blob of dead cats that contained slightly differing dead cats contiguously, and that blob emitted a blob of photons.

Comment: I thought that you wrote the answer in order to obfuscate the vagueness and pretend that it makes sense! ;-) You know, this idea about their life in different Universes is exactly the feature that quantum mechanics *forbids*. The point is that the two "blobs" of the wave function may always return to each other and interfere. The double slit experiment makes this point obvious. So every "apparent split" into several blobs may always be reversed in principle. That's why the worlds can't ever exactly split. That's really the basic point of quantum mechanics - interference is possible.

Comment: The split of the world into two or several worlds with different "classical" outcomes of measurements is always just an approximation, and it's a conscious observer - whether or not we use these spiritually sounding words or any words that just mask it into a more boring language - who must make the decision that he really perceives something, and therefore the approximation may be done. But a more rigorous external observer  is always possible who allows all the "blobs" to reinterfere in the future and who can study their interference.

Comment: So there can't exist any "universal observer" in quantum mechanics - that would be equivalent to making quantum mechanics independent of observers but quantum mechanics simply cannot be formulated independently of observers. These are the basic features that Heisenberg and pals had to realize in the early 1920s, the true heart of the new theory, the reason why they (especially Heisenberg and Born and partly Dirac) got their Nobel prizes and why we celebrate them. To deny these things means to deny quantum mechanics. Someone calls this denial "XY interpretation of QM" but it's still the denial.